# Hide xaml element when null

Tags: xaml, uwp, template10

We have a UWP app using Template10. There is a textblock and textbox which show a discount. We wish to hide the textblock when `ViewModel.Discount` is null.

In App.xaml we have defined a converter

```
<T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter x:Key="HideWhenNullConverter" When="{x:Null}">
    <T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
        <Visibility>Collapsed</Visibility>
    </T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter.Value>
    <T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
    </T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter.Otherwise>
</T10Converters:ValueWhenConverter>
```

In the View we set the visibility of the TextBlock

```
Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.Discount, Converter={StaticResource HideWhenNullConverter}}"
```

In the ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    decimal? _Discount = default(decimal?);
    public decimal? Discount
    {
        get
        {
            return _Discount;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value == 0) value = null;
            Set(ref _Discount, value);
        }
    }
```

However the textblock is always visible even if the value of `ViewModel.Discount` is null. How do we hide the textblock when `ViewModel.Discount` is null

Comment: You could also state that the Visibility logic is the responsibility of the ViewModel. The latest UWP can bind Visibility to a bool directly. Imagine you later have additional business rules, like a max price or so.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Nice, thanks for mentioning that - I've somehow [missed this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34846.uwp-compiled-binding-windows-10-anniversary-update.aspx).

Comment: In _14393_, `Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.Discount.HasValue, Mode=OneWay}"`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Justin XL but I couldn't get this to work in 14393

Comment: @Vague ahh I think I was wrong as HasValue might only work for the first time. So might still need to create a new bool property?

Comment: @Justin XL the answer accepted is probably the best as it does not require creation and setting of another property.

Comment: Actually if you are using 14393 you should avoid converters as they are slow. Instead you can bind a function directly.

Comment: Yes @Justin XL that's what we have found ... converters are terribly slow. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: "creation and setting of another property" is not a problem when it's in the right place (and the VM usually is the right place).

Comment: @JustinXL - `Discount.HasValue` will not have INPC implemented.

Comment: @HenkHolterman your right. I realized that after I posted the comment. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've tried with [Template10's source](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Template10%20(Library)/Converters/ValueWhenConverter.cs) it should work. I suspect that you are just missing redefinition of *Mode* with `x:Bind`, which as default is *OneTime*. Try like this:

```
Visibility="{x:Bind ViewModel.Discount, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HideWhenNullConverter}}"
```